# Iterating objects in a slot

Tags: vue.js

I would like to pass X number of components into a slot and loop through them. Something like this...

```
<Foo>
 <template #abc>
   <Bar />
   <Bar />
   <Bar />
 </template>
 <template #def>Baz</template>
</Foo>
```

Foo.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col v-for="child in $children" :key="child">
        <slot name="abc"></slot>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <slot name="def"></slot>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
<template>
```

I feel like I'm pretty close with the syntax, but I'm not sure if this is possible.  Am I on the right track? I know that slots have a this.$children but I'm not sure how to find the components in it by template.

Comment: You are not using named slots correctly because you gave the same name for all of them inside that loop. Which thing may lead to paranormal activities

Comment: Yes, that's the part I'm stuck on. Can you provide an example of how to do that?

Comment: I'm lazy for the moment, but maybe you can try this: <slot name="`${key}`"></slot>

Comment: But how would that work since the template dictates the name abc and its contents can be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to achieve this is to use a `render` function. Within a `render` function you can manipulate the array of child VNodes for the slot.

The example below inserts and extra item between each pair of children. Text nodes and comment nodes are filtered out by checking for the `tag`.

```js
const MyList = {
  render (h) {
    const slot = this.$slots.default || []
    const children = []
    
    for (let index = 0; index < slot.length; ++index) {
      const child = slot[index]
      
      // Ignore
      if (child.tag) {
        if (index) {
          children.push(h('div', null, ['Between']))
        }
      
        children.push(child)
      }      
    }
    
    return h('div', null, children)
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    MyList
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-list>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div v-if="false">Hidden</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
  </my-list>
</div>
```

As far as I'm aware a template will only allow you to include the slot's contents as a whole, without access to the individual children.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm missing something but this doesn't look like it explicitly uses templates/slots

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 It is using slots. See `this.$slots.default` on the first line of the `render` function.

Comment: I apologize but this example looks too different from my original and I'm not sure how to map between the two

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 To some extent that was my point. I don't believe you can achieve what you're trying to achieve using a template. Behind the scenes Vue compiles all templates down into `render` functions. Writing your own `render` function gives you a lot more flexibility but at the expense of readability. Have a read of https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html. Don't let the mention of JSX in the title put you off, that isn't really what it's about. Sooner or later any non-trivial application is going to need a component that uses a `render` function.

Comment: I took a read but that's a bit beyond me. I'm not sure how to translate/mix&match the example I have which uses multiple slots into something like what you've shown. Thanks anyways though!