Subscribe to a child event programatically in Vue3
Is it possible to subscribe to an event given a reference to a component in Vue?
I would like to subscribe to any events fired by child input components.
In Vue2 this would work by simply using componentInstance.$on('eventName');
This has been deprecated and there are no other documented ways of doing it. Considering this is such a basic feature, it should be possible to simply subscribe to child event in some way if I have the reference/instance of it?
The docs say that $listeners has been replaced by $attrs. But even if I set componentInstance.attrs.onEventName as the documentation would imply, nothing happens.
I am obviously going about this in the wrong way. I simply want to be able to listen to events that are fired by the children of a wrapping component.
Say, in a TabGroup and the children would be Tabs.
This seems like a common pattern, yet there is no straightforward way of handling it?
How would one do this in a simple way?
[Edit]: I am not looking for a way to subscribe to an event within the template. Since the idea is to iterate over children, I do not have access to the template and can't use v-bind or v-on. Ideally I could just iterate over the children, either as vnodes or something else and then subscribe to their events manually, as was previously possible by using $on.
Especially in recursive situations it would seem this is no longer possible in an easy way. It might be possible using render functions however examples that I have seen would be overkill for such a simple task.
Is there really no way to have a simple loop that subscribes to each child?
[Edit] Here's a code example:
<script setup>
  const slots = useSlots();
  // Provides a list of VNodes
  const defaultSlot = slots.default?.();

  // How do I subscribe to events on these VNodes?
</script>


<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>



Consider updating the code with an example that shows your case. Event listeners are translated to "on..." props internally, so potentially you need to process children vnodes and add it, this is conveniently done in render function

@EstusFlask I think a render function is the way to go since you could then manipulate the children directly, similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031324/1087372
However I am slightly confused as to why this would be needed, since all information is technically available and could be solved a lot easier by looping through an exisiting list and subscribing with $on as was previously possible.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72422082/3731501

Very short answer: Child component emits the event: @click="$emit('myCustomEvent')"
Parent component subscribes to event: <parent @my-custom-event="handleMyCustomEvent">
That's it, you don't need anything else. Below is long-story explanation of why you don't have refs in events anymore.
There was rewrite of event handling in Vue3.
You can subscribe to an event emitted by a child component in any parent component, on any level, by declaring event listener. Any event bubbling up can be subscribed to by any parent component within bubble up, you don't need refs anymore, it isn't handled by refs anymore.
That means that the event listening outside of what the components bubble up is not a library feature any more.
Here is the link to a relevant section in documentation https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#migration-strategy
If, for some reason, you need to react to something happening outside of bubble-up cone, say, if there is a sibling components or even separate modules and you need to listen to event in one of them, there is a number of ways to handle it, described in the docs. Me, I'm using Pinia and I've never wanted anything else. Reactivity for Pinia store and watchers provide all the imaginable functionality our group of programmers' needs for our rather large and complex applications. I really like Pinia. :)
I have looked at your example and while I recognise the functions, never in my life I've used a useSlots function, I've never even thought that I need it.
I have included a small example on vue playground where I

provide easily readable and accessible template for a slot component (it is an inline template, but it can just as easily be a separate file component),
I iterate over an array of data to create a number of child slots (may be it's not the iteration you've meant, of course, but it was what I meant by the word)
link a couple of functions into that slotted component to capture a button click event (certainly it can be any other event) to be executed either in external component or a parent component, which covers all my use cases.

Playground very rough Example of slots and events in them
That kind of covers all the usecases I've ever needed or can think of, of the top of my head. Obviously they don't cover your needs, otherwise you wouldn't use useSlots, but you would need to expand on your example and explanations for me to provide any more examples; I'm not familiar with useSlots and rendering enough to just think of something right away.

The idea would be to iterate children inside a slot, it's not possible to bind directly to a child component because it's not known and there is no template to bind to. I think it could be possible with render functions as someone else commented.
Pinia is most likely not the way to go for such a simple setup, and would add an overhead which should not be necessary.

I really miss something here. You don't need to bind directly to a child component in any case, as I understand it. Say, I have a table, and I iterate over table column slots, but of course each such column slot can emit an event captured by the table.
You wrote "Since the idea is to iterate over children, I do not have access to the template" - and I just can't understand it. I often iterate over children and I of course have access to their templates, and add events or listen to their native events, so clearly I misunderstand something. Can you show a code fragment?

Docs also mention "Provide / inject allow a component to communicate with its slot contents. This is useful for tightly-coupled components that are always used together." It is a relatively simple mechanism of communication between components - https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject - Although if you can use provide-inject, you likely could use emit.  I am really missing something here. :)

I have added a code example for clarification. I don't know how to iterate over slots, how do you what you said: "I iterate over table column slots". I can't find any intuitive way to do this without using a render function for instance.

I have added a playground example which shows how I usually go about working with slots and events with them, processing those events in either parent component or upper level component, depending on my needs. Obviously it's a totally different way than you do, my way is very simple, but may be it will be useful for you. (I've kind of used your code as a start for slottedChild.vue component, although, obviously, slottedChild.vue would be a parent for actual slot content.)

I was not clear enough, I don't want to subscribe to events from the consuming end. I want to subscribe to children of the slot within the actual component. In my example I do not have access to the children within the template. I only have the VNodes from the slot directly.
